# Best Approach for Stacking an Unknown Number of Rows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF GUI setup like this currently:

[image]

The "Check for Third Party Updates" button will query the machine for outdated application installs and display the results, each update grouped in its own row/section with some text describing the update and a button allowing them to initiate the install.

I have a class built for third party updates that contains application name, version, installpath, message to display, etc. My question is largely how to implement the visual components. Every time the list of "apps to be updated" is iterated through and a member is found, a new row needs to be generated with common elements (button, text, picture,etc.). And I don't know how many rows might be generated, so I need to allow for the potential of scrolling down within the tab. Is a listbox control the way to go? How can I setup a visual template for the rows that are dynamically created to adhere to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ListBox would be a sensible approach. You would have to create a DataTemplate for the ListBoxItems and assign that to the `ItemTemplate` property of the ListBox, as described in [Styling and Templating an ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DataTemplating_ItemsControl). All the rest, like the ability to select items, or to scroll through the list, is of course done automatically by the ListBox control.

It might look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ThirdPartyUpdates}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding AppIcon}" Margin="5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppName}" Margin="5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppVersion}" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The view model for the above ListBox would be something like this:

```
public class ThirdPartyUpdate
{
    public string AppIcon { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppVersion { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ThirdPartyUpdate> ThirdPartyUpdates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemsControl and bind it to a collection of your Class and use ItemsControl's template to bind your data to whichever control you want. Check out this [Example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/)

For each item in the collection you will have a row created. Surround the item control with a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Set the VerticalScrollbar visibility to auto so that it will be visible only when required. And if you set a maximumheight to a value you feel right and set the height to auto. It will grow till the maximum height and the scroll bar will be visible if items are added beyond that.